# Get WebDataGrid page size in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, infragistics, webdatagrid

I am using `Infragistic` `WebDataGrid`. When it load first, it gets data from database as data source in `Page_Load` event. On some UI interaction, I am rebinding it with `JQuery.Ajax` call by clearing it and appending new html using `append` method of JQuery. It works fine except I am not able to persist page size that I have declared in mark-up. Is there any way to accessing page size in javascript?

Or is there anything else I can do to achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the page size on the client like this:

```
$find("WebDataGridID").get_behaviors().get_paging().get_pageSize();
```